# I am getting cookie when I am using wget but no cookies when using groovy script

Tags: http, groovy

Here is the wget command :

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=auth_user --http-password=auth_pass --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data 'user_login=username&pass=password' https://www.helloworld.com/login.php
```

Here is the groovy script:

```
static List<String> login(String baseUrl, String path, query, method = Method.POST) {
        try {
            def ret = null
            def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)

            http.request(method, ContentType.URLENC) {
            uri.path = path
            uri.query = query

            headers.'Authorization' = "Basic ${"auth_user:auth_pass".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()}"

            // response handler for a success response code
            response.success = { resp, data ->    

                println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"

                resp.getHeaders('Set-Cookie').each {

                    def cookie = it.value.split(";").toString()
                    println cookie
                    .add(cookie)
                }
                println 'Response : ' + resp.getData()
            }
         }
         return cookies

        } catch (groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace()

        } catch (java.net.ConnectException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace()

        }
    }

def url = "https://www.helloworld.com/login.php"
def path = ""
def query = [ user_login: "username@calypso", pass: "password" ]

// Submit a request via POST
def response = login(url, path, query)
```

So wget command get me cookie but this groovy script doesn't. This is the response I am getting:

```
response status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Header:
 Date : Mon, 28 Mar 2016 19:56:20 GMT
 Server : Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
 Last-Modified : Sat, 03 May 2003 21:37:01 GMT
 ETag : "56b0013-1d4-3bcc9546cd940"
 Accept-Ranges : bytes
 Content-Length : 468
 Keep-Alive : timeout=999
 Connection : Keep-Alive
 Content-Type : text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not do authentication by yourself. If only successful authentication creates a cookie this could explain the phenomenon.

Try

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)
http.auth.basic 'auth_user', 'auth_pass'
```

See also the [documentation](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki). Additionally the non-empty response body might give you a hint about what's going wrong.

Comment: OK. Then I suggest to use Wireshark, tcpdump, or something like that to see what's going over the network and work out the differences between wget and Groovy requests.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I just figured out I am setting uri.path = "". Commenting it works

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling toString on your array after splitting. Try getting the first value of the array:

```
String cookie = it.value.split(';')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks but I think thats not the problem... I am not at all receiving cookie

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the cookie is httpOnly and your groovy script is honoring that, but wget is not ?